# OpenSwitch OPX Building new image

Tags: debian, docker

I've got two Dell EMC S4128F-ON Switches at my work. We want to use these but they didn't come with OS10 from dell.

I found OpenSwitch, it should work with these switches.

The problem with OpenSwitch is that they are outdated, their release .bin files contain stretch with urls to deb.debian.org/stretch but stretch moved to the archive. Now I think my only chance to use these 2 switches is getting OpenSwitch working.

When trying to install these .bin files using ONIE it gives a error that it can not reach deb.debian.org/stretch.

I found their github with a guide to build a new image, I've tried that but it gives me this error: "The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.", but I can not find where to edit the build repository to use archive.debian.org...

Is there someone willing to help me in the right direction or even build a image for me?

URL to the build repository: https://github.com/open-switch/opx-build